# Sort the JTable by JRadioButton

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable, jscrollpane

I want sort the `JTable` by the `JRadioButton` component's `ActionListener` method. When I click "name" the table will sorted out by name. But now I click name radio button, all is blank.

The Main code for query the database all is fine. So I have problem for add another table to the `JScrollPane`. For the simplicity, I deleted all the import related code. But all the code is  working except the radio button's action listener.

[image: Jtable]

```
public class JtableDemo extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private static JFrame frame;
    JTextField textField;
    JScrollPane scrollPanel;
    JRadioButton nameButton = new JRadioButton("name");
    JRadioButton departmentButton  =new JRadioButton("department");
    JRadioButton salaryButton =new JRadioButton("Salary");
    JRadioButton dateButton = new JRadioButton("date");
    ButtonGroup orderbyButtonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    JTable jTable = new JTable();
    String orderbyname = "select * from emp where salary >6000 order by name";
    String orderbydepartment = "select * from emp where salary >6000 order by department";
    String orderbysalary = "select * from emp where salary >6000 order by salary";
    public JtableDemo() throws SQLException {
        nameButton.addActionListener(this);
        departmentButton.addActionListener(this);
        salaryButton.addActionListener(this);
        dateButton.addActionListener(this);
        orderbyButtonGroup.add(nameButton);
        orderbyButtonGroup.add(departmentButton);
        orderbyButtonGroup.add(salaryButton);
        orderbyButtonGroup.add(dateButton);

        this.add(nameButton);
        this.add(departmentButton);
        this.add(salaryButton);
        this.add(dateButton);

        String query = "select * from emp where salary>? ";
        PreparedStatement statement = Main.connection.prepareStatement(query);
        statement.setInt(1,6000);
        //statement.setString(2,"id");
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
        jTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(resultSet));
        jTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500,200));
        jTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jTable);
        add(scrollPane);
        String title = "all emp's salary less than 5600";
        this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(),title, TitledBorder.CENTER,TitledBorder.TOP));
    }

    public static void createandShowGUI() throws SQLException {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JtableDemo newContentPane = new JtableDemo();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true);
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource()==nameButton) {
            try {
                JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jTable);
                PreparedStatement orderbystatement = Main.connection.prepareStatement(orderbyname);
                //orderbystatement.setString(1,"name");
                ResultSet resultSet = orderbystatement.executeQuery();
                jTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(resultSet));
                jTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500,200));
                jTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

            } catch (SQLException throwables) {
                throwables.printStackTrace();
            } }
        if(e.getSource()==departmentButton) { System.out.println("testdepartmentButton"); }
        if(e.getSource()==salaryButton) { System.out.println("testsalaryButton"); }
        if(e.getSource()==dateButton) { System.out.println("testdateButton"); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you create a new `JScrollPane`?  `JTable` is also capable of sorting the contents itself, see [Sorting and Filtering from the `JTable` examples](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting)

Comment: Wow, Thanks. That is So cool.